# How to reproduce this carsh in Android Emulator android Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I am working on an Android app which uses WebView. I am seeing on FirebaseCrashlytics that some of the users the app is crashing. Most of the device are fronm Samsung, TCL and LGE. I see that there are many suggestions on Stackoverflow how to fix the problem. But I am asking a different question. I am not sure how to reproduce the issue as it is happening only in few devices.

**My question is this**

Is there a way to reproduce this issue on any Android Emulator?

> Here is the Crash report from Firebase Crashlytics

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
Failed to create webview.
  org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine (CordovaWebViewImpl.java:82)
  org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl (CordovaActivity.java:338)
  com.adp.innovationlabroseland.BaseMainActivity.onCreate (BaseMainActivity.java:30)
  com.adp.e.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:12)
  android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8075)
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:997)

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Constructor.java)
  org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl (CordovaActivity.java:338)

Caused by android.util.AndroidRuntimeException
  android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load 
  WebView provider: No WebView installed
  android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass (WebViewFactory.java:435)
  org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.<init> (SystemWebViewEngine.java:82)
```

Comment: The WebView on Android is a separate app by itself. If phones running android don't have the viewbiew "app" installed, they cannot use the WebView. The only way to test is to remove the WebView "app" from the Android device.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en_CA&gl=US

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did disable the WebView in the Android Samsung Phone(Real Device) And the app crashed. But I did not get the same crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

### Android 10 and Android 11

**AFAIK:** Before Android 10(API Level 29) all the  Web Content in your app is rendered from Google Chrome In-built WebView.
But from Android 10 the WebView is shipped as an independent app known as [Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en_CA&gl=US).

#### How to reproduce this crash?

As mentioned by Eric in the comments you need to disable the WebView.

**In Android 10 and above**

1. Go to Settings
2. Search for Android System WebView
3. Disable the app

This is how the page looks like in Settings

[image]

#### Note:

In some devices you may not find the the App System WebView in Settings.
You can search it in Settings> Developer